# Image stuck in another div's image

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I've recently picked up HTML/CSS since I suddenly needed to make a website for my app.
This particular page is very basic. One word (in huge size) followed by an image. These two are centered. They problem is that when I try to get a "Download on the App Store" cenetered beneath them.
Here's a picture:

[image]

I'm not sure why the App Store image gets stuck in one of the other objects. 
I suspect that is has something to do with :

```
     display: flex;
     -webkit-align-items: center;
     align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
```

I have tried to use clear: both;, display: block; padding and whatnot. Nothing seems to work, and I couldn't find anything by using Google. This might be a very basic question, or me doing something stupid. However, I will greatly appreciate any effort to help.

Here comes  the HTML:

```
 <div id="blue">

     <div id="ytfil"> ytfil </div>

     <div class="imgcontainer"><img id="iphonepicture" src="iphonebluesite.png"> </div>

    <div id="container"><img id="appstore" src="App_store_logo.svg"> </div>

</div>
```

And here we go with the CSS

```
 #blue{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #4689D0;
display:         flex;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}

#ytfil{
font-size: 450px;
color: white;
font-family: helvetica;
margin-right: 50px;
}

#iphonepicture {
margin-right: -200px;
}


#container {
display: block;
}   

 #appstore {
width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post an image showing what you are trying to achieve? It's not very clear from your code / description

Comment: Hey! 
Apologies for that. I have now included an imgur link!

Comment: You mean [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/q35wgpes/2/embedded/result/)? (Source: http://jsfiddle.net/q35wgpes/2/)

Comment: Exactly like that, but with the "ytfil" and 200x450 centered vertically as well!
Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q35wgpes/5

Comment: Wow, almost there. Thanks! 
Althought the 200x450 doesn't seem to be able to get at the same height as the "ytfil" text. Even when I change padding/margin.
It's supposed to be where my very professinally drawn red box is:
http://imgur.com/zQBmr0O

Comment: This is what I see: http://imgur.com/Z4nqoWk Check the markup and the css, I've simplified it from what you had quite a bit.

Comment: Added as an answer; feel free to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

```css
#blue{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #4689D0;
  text-align: center;
}

#ytfil{
  font-size: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

#container {
  display: block;
}   

#appstore {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="blue">
      <div id="ytfil"> ytfil </div>
      <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img id="iphonepicture" src="http://placehold.it/300x150/&text=Iphone"> 
      </div>
      <div id="container">
        <img id="appstore" src="http://placehold.it/200x150/&text=Logo"> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry again if I was unclear. The "iPhone" is supposed be on the same row as the "ytfil" and the "logo" should be under both of them.
Just like my imgur image is, but with ONLY the "App Store" logo moved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but I think you're issue is using the `display: flex` CSS property.

I made a fiddle with what I think you're trying to do but I could be wrong. Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/f3aarh5v/

```
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #4689D0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
#appstore {
    width: 400px;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

**EDIT:**
You wanted the pic CENTERED beneath the ytfill

do this instead:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
#appstore {
    align-self: center;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `display: flex` to do this, you can simply `text-align: center` with (the unmentioned need) `display: table-cell;` to get `vertical-align: middle` working.

I've simplified both the markup and the css (although the latter may look like more, it's simpler and better-supported).

```
<div id="blue">
    <div id='container'>
        <span id="ytfil">ytfil</span>
        <img id="iphonepicture" src="http://placehold.it/200x450" />
        <br/>
        <img id="appstore" src="http://placehold.it/120x45" />
    </div>
</div>

#blue {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #4689D0;
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#ytfil {
    font-size: 450px;
    color: white;
    font-family: helvetica;
}
#iphonepicture {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 65px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q35wgpes/5/ (Fullscreen: https://jsfiddle.net/q35wgpes/5/embedded/result/)